# How can i have 2D bounding box on a sequence of RGBD frames from a 3D bounding box in point clouds?

Tags: python, opencv, point-clouds, bounding-box, open3d

i have a 3d point clouds of my object by using Open3d reconstruction system ( makes point clouds by a sequence of RGBD frames) also I created a 3d bounding box on the object in point clouds
my question is how can I have 2d bounding box on all of the RGB frames at the same coordinates of 3d bounding box?
my idea Is to project 3d bb to 2d bb but as it is clear, the position of the object is different in each frame, so I do not know how can i use this approach?
i appreciate any help or solution, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- calculate points for the eight corners of your box
- *transform* those points from the world frame into your chosen camera frame
- project the points, apply lens distortion if needed.

OpenCV has functions for some of these operations and supports you with matrix math for the rest.

I would guess that Open3d gives you pose matrices for all the cameras. you use those to transform from the world coordinate frame to any camera's frame.

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually i am new in this field if you could explain in more detail or give me some examples, that would be a great help, thanks...besides I have points of eight corners, is there any program(or function) to do transformation?

Comment: transformation is matrix multiplication (matrix times vector). pose matrices are 4x4 (or a 3x3 rotation matrix and 3x1 translation vector). `cv::projectPoints` to apply the camera's (OpenCV) projection matrix (3x3) and distortion coefficients. projectPoints can also take an "rvec" (which is an axis and magnitude=angle) and tvec if you don't have a pose matrix for the camera but those two pieces of info.

Comment: sorry i have another question, i have pose matrices and I extracted tvec (3*1) and rotation matrix(3*3) from it then I just use cv.Rodrigues to get the rvec then I did projection but the result was not acceptable, is it the correct way?

Comment: i have not done the transformation first because in the document it is written cv.projectPoints will do the projection from world coordinates to pixel coordinates...